# Rails 4 + AngularJS: templateUrl for directive not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to create a directive in AngularJS to split my HTML into reusable partials:

app/assets/javascripts/products/directives/products.js:

```
app.directive('productsfilter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "/templates/filter-template.html"
  }
});
```

However, the templates are not found:

`Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /templates/filter-template.html http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/$compile/tpload?p0=%2Ftemplates%2Ffilter-template.html`

I also tried `../templates/filter-template.html` and `templates/filter-template.html` but neither worked. Is it because of Rails's asset pipeline?

Here's my folder tree from within app/assets/javascripts:

```
└── products
    ├── controllers
    │   ├── mens_controller.js
    │   ├── productscontroller.js
    │   ├── womens_eyeglasses_controller.js
    │   └── womens_sunglasses_controller.js
    ├── directives
    │   └── products.js
    ├── filters
    │   └── productsfilters.js
    ├── services
    │   └── productsservices.js
    └── templates
        └── filter-template.html
```

Comment: What are urls to retrieve another javascript files? The templateUrl should be relative to them.

Comment: Perhaps it's because I'm using Rails routes and not Angular routes? It looks like Rails is looking for a file in the public folder: `GET http://localhost:3000/templates/filter-template.html 404 Not Found`

Comment: Yes, it's looking in the public folder. The url should be longer than that. May be `assets/javascripts/products/templates/filter-template.html` or shorter/longer.

Comment: I decided to put my templates.html files into public/templates. It worked after that

Comment: I racked my brain on this for an hour and all I had to do was restart the rails server

Comment: As run Tarm said, I had the same problem and the url should be relative to the javascripts. So your templateUrl should have been products/templates/filter-template.html.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered same issue. My path to my template was:

```
assets/templates/partials/question/multipleChoice.html
```

when I moved the template into:

```
assets/templates/multipleChoice.html
```

the embedded:

```
<%= asset_path('multipleChoice.html') %>
```

worked. Perhaps, it is the limitation of

```
asset_path()
```

method to dig much deeper.

To make the method be able to find the template, I pointed it out, like this:

```
templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('partials/question/multipleChoiceSingleAnswer.html') %>"
```

and it worked. (of course, you have to change the extension to .js.erb).

I don't want to place my templates inside the public folder. I want Rails to handle it for me and make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive('productsfilter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "filter-template.html"
  }
});
```

Use this gem if you are not using it.

```
gem 'angular-rails-templates'
```

Worked for me.